# this.id is undefined. I get this error while coding the classic tic tac toe

Tags: javascript, function, this, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to call the tile id with this. id from an EventListener in another function.

Like this:

```
const setGame = () => {
    board = [
        [' ', ' ', ' '],
        [' ', ' ', ' '],
        [' ', ' ', ' ']
    ]

    for(let r = 0 ; r < 3; r++) {
        for(let c = 0 ; c < 3; c++) {
            let tile = document.createElement("div")
            tile.id = r.toString() + "-" + c.toString();
            tile.classList.add("col-4", "box", "d-flex", "justify-content-center", "align-items-center");
            
            tile.addEventListener("click", setTile);
            document.getElementById("board").append(tile);
        }
    }
}

const setTile = () => {
    if (gameOver) {
        return;
    }
    let coords = this.id.split("-")  //splits the id string "1-1" into an array["1", "1"]
    let r = parseInt(coords[0]);
    let c = parseInt(coords[1]);

    board[r][c] = currPlayer;
    this.innerText = currPlayer;

}
```

I am not an expert with "this"... I know it calls an object from a class... In this case it would be calling the tile object when I click on the div element that i am creating.. but on console I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.id is undefined
    setTile http://127.0.0.1:5501/js/game.js:54
    setGame http://127.0.0.1:5501/js/game.js:43
    onload http://127.0.0.1:5501/js/game.js:27
    EventHandlerNonNull* http://127.0.0.1:5501/js/game.js:26
```

With the first function setGame().. I create the divs that create the 3 x 3 board and give each div ids like 0,0 0,1 0,2 1,0 .. etc. And add an eventlistener so when we click in any of them.. it executes the following function, setTile()

When setTile() is called on the click, I was expecting to get the id from tiles (div element), calling tiles with  `this.` to convert the string into an array and use them to tell the html where the current Player is on the board.

Comment: What object are you expecting `this` to refer to, and why?

Comment: To tile... tile.addEventListener("click", setTile);

Comment: Because then with setTile( ) i am trying to get its id to then do something with it later...

Comment: "Arrow functions don't have their own bindings to `this`, `arguments`, or `super`, and should not be used as methods."
[Arrow Function documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: I changed my arrow function to normal functions and it worked!!! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved in multiple ways. But first you need to know that [arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) don't handle `this` the same as a regular [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function). So in your `setTile` function, `this` will either reference the first regular function expression that is a wrapping your code, or the `window` object.

Besides that, using `this` in an event handler can be hard to understand as `this` could reference many things beside the element that the event listener has been added to.

The easiest workaround is to pass the `tile` element to the `setTile` function as an argument and use the passed `tile` instead of `this`.

```
const setGame = () => {
  board = [
    [' ', ' ', ' '],
    [' ', ' ', ' '],
    [' ', ' ', ' ']
  ];

  const boardElement = document.getElementById("board");

  for (let r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
    for (let c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
      let tile = document.createElement("div")
      tile.id = r.toString() + "-" + c.toString();
      tile.classList.add("col-4", "box", "d-flex", "justify-content-center", "align-items-center");

      tile.addEventListener("click", () => {
        setTile(tile);
      });

      boardElement.append(tile);
    }
  }
}

const setTile = (tile) => {
  if (gameOver) {
    return;
  }

  let coords = tile.id.split("-") //splits the id string "1-1" into an array["1", "1"]
  let r = parseInt(coords[0]);
  let c = parseInt(coords[1]);

  board[r][c] = currPlayer;
  tile.innerText = currPlayer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case you should capture the **event** in your "setTile" callback function instead of using this.

Try to do this change in your event callback.

*Also check that your "board" array is within reach of your callback function.*

```
const setTile = (event) => {
    if (gameOver) {
        return;
    }
    let coords = event.target.id.split("-")  //splits the id string "1-1" into an array["1", "1"]
    let r = parseInt(coords[0]);
    let c = parseInt(coords[1]);

    board[r][c] = currPlayer;
    this.innerText = currPlayer;

}
```